# Is it possible to retrieve old answers to deleted questions?

Tags: support

There is a live question about whether global warming will cause an oxygen shortage.

I remember writing a (controversial because of original research) answer to a question about how long atmospheric oxygen would ask if photosynthesis stopped. It contained some relevant references to the live question. But the question was deleted by its owner after some controversy and I can't find it any more.

Is is possible to retrieve old questions and answers if they were deleted?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, on the main site search you can include the search term `deleted:1`, in addition to your search term:

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3A1+%22global+warming%22

More detail on searching available in the help centre: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/searching

Comment: You'll only be able to see *other people's* deleted posts if you have [at least 10,000 rep](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: The `deleted` operator only finds your own posts, and you need 10k rep for it to work. Only mods can freely search all deleted posts.